# jms producer side reliability

Tags: java, jms

I found a lot of reading material about jms receiver side reliability (Acknowledgement, persistence, transacted) , bot no reading material about jms producer side reliability . I mean how can I be sure the jms broker got my producer message ? is it only matter of catch jmsException around the send method ?

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have a very detailed catch block with exceptions.
`JMSException`; `Exception`; `Throwable` (there might be others depending on your JMS spec implementation - WebSphere, WebLogic, ... etc)

One important thing to not forget is to check the

> dead letter queue

. That will give you messages that did not make it through. You might find there other type of exceptions that need to be handled.